# Files not updating on google cloud platform instance

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, filezilla

i am using google cloud platform and i have created an instance from compute engine. i installed  apache server and then fresh laravel installation using ssh. All my laravel files exist on this path
var/www/html
but now when i am trying to edit any file its not reflecting. When i access my site using this link
https://project-id.appspot.com/
it only display a fresh laravel installation. not reflecting new changes.

I am using filezilla to update files.

Comment: You can't edit an App Engine app by SSHing in. That's just there [for debugging](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance). Make your changes locally, then deploy a new version of the app with the new code.

Answer (score 1):

The link you have provided is the URL format used by App Engine applications, not a Compute Engine instance. I believe you may be confusing the two.

To view the changes you have done to the files in a Compute Engine instance, you have to access the [external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#externaladdresses) of said instance, just as you would with a regular machine or VM.

Therefore, navigate to the [Compute Engine section](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute) of the Cloud Console and look for the external IP of the Compute Engine instance where you have installed Laravel.

Comment: can you please let me know the path of App Engine files?

Comment: Just as @ceejayoz said, this is not what the SSH functionality for App Engine is for, nor will it work. If that is how you desire to edit those files, I'm afraid the installation process of both Apache and Laravel has to be done on a Compute Engine instance, where you will be able to access and modify the files - seeing the changes reflected on the external IP of the instance.

Comment: @Aamish If you still want to do it in App Engine, the files have to be edited in e.g the Cloud Shell, and the changes will be seen after re-deploying the GAE app version: cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-apps Please bear in mind that App Engine is mainly meant for developing and hosting Web applications.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys.

so this url http://app-name.appspot.com/ will display app that will be installed on app engine not on compute instance. right?

Comment: @Aamish It is meant for App Engine, yes. Here's the documentation as reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/deploying-the-application#viewing_your_deployed_application

Comment: ok thanks. there is another issue that. When i am trying to open my static external ip in my browser i am getting error. i have enabled http/https firewals and port 80 and 8080 is also active. do you have any idea why is that?